# Why does F# generic struct have extra __dummy field?

Tags: generics, compiler-construction, struct, f#, sizeof

Using F# Interactive, you can verify the following sizes:

```
// sizeof<A> = 4 bytes
type A (i: int) = struct end

// sizeof<B<int>> = 8 bytes (use any type parameter)
type B<'T> (i: int) = struct end
```

The reason for the extra size seems to be the presence of an integer `__dummy` field in the generic case. Using F# Interactive again, you can see this using `typeof`:

- `typeof<A>` shows `DeclaredFields = [|Int32 i|]`
- `typeof<B<int>>` shows `DeclaredFields = [|Int32 i; Int32 __dummy|]`

I don't understand why this `__dummy` field has been added.

I think the code responsible for adding it is here:

https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Compiler.Service/blob/master/src/fsharp/ilxgen.fs

[Line 6377](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Compiler.Service/blob/master/src/fsharp/ilxgen.fs#L6377) shows this:

```
if requiresExtraField then 
    yield mkILInstanceField("__dummy",cenv.g.ilg.typ_int32,None,ILMemberAccess.Assembly) ]
```

[Line 6290](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Compiler.Service/blob/master/src/fsharp/ilxgen.fs#L6290) is where `requiresExtraField` is defined:

```
let requiresExtraField = 
    let isEmptyStruct = 
        (match ilTypeDefKind with ILTypeDefKind.ValueType -> true | _ -> false) &&
        // All structs are sequential by default 
        // Structs with no instance fields get size 1, pack 0
        tycon.AllFieldsAsList |> List.exists (fun f -> not f.IsStatic)

    isEmptyStruct && cenv.opts.workAroundReflectionEmitBugs && not tycon.TyparsNoRange.IsEmpty
```

I assume that `isEmptyStruct` is supposed to mean that the struct does not have any instance fields. But the code as written is testing whether the struct *does* have any instance fields, which for most structs, including mine, is going to be true. I think the last part of the final test is whether there are any generic type parameters. So `requiresExtraField` is `false` for `type A` (not generic) and `true` for `type B` (generic type).

Is this a compiler bug, or is the code correct? If it is correct, then what's the purpose of this `__dummy` field? Is there some way I can avoid having it?

As another test, I removed my one and only instance field, and not surprisingly, I got the following sizes, showing that the `__dummy` field was no longer added:

```
// sizeof<AA> = 1
type AA = struct end

// sizeof<BB<int>> = 1
type BB<'T> = struct end
```

The reason I want to have a value type, rather than a reference type, is that I will be storing lots of these objects in my data structures, not just passing them around.

Comment: "cenv.opts.workAroundReflectionEmitBugs" suggests that this is a workaround to some reflection emit bug. Have you checked if C# does the same thing? - A quick look at the code history shows that this dates back to at least November 2010, F# 2.0 - the earliest version of the code available online AFAIK.

Comment: Since sizeof<B<char>> = 4 in a program, is its size in the interactive really an issue for you?

Comment: @jyoung: Oh, I never realized that this was only the case with F# Interactive. I just tried sizeof<B<char>> in a program, like you said, and it gives 4, whereas F# Interactive gives 8. Then my issue is solved, thank you! I found that source file using Google, so I didn't know the bigger picture of what it is for. In the corresponding fsi file, the public `IlxAssemblyGenerator` type at the end says that it is _An incremental ILX code generator for a single assembly_. Just for my edification, what is that all about?

Comment: Type the lines let f()=1;; let g()=f();; let f()=2;; g();;  You'll see that g() is still 1.  So a 'new' f() was (incrementally) added to the assembly, but the 'old' f() is still there being referenced by the previous increments of the code.

Comment: @jyoung: Thanks. So the "ILX code generator" is only used in situations like F# Interactive, and is not part of the regular F# compiler, I assume.

Comment: I think it is the same generator. Your problem arises because of the fscopts.fs's line: 'workAroundReflectionEmitBugs=tcConfig.isInteractive; // REVIEW: is this still required?'

Comment: @jyoung: Ah ha, the mystery is now solved. Thanks once again. By the way, how do I mark my own posting as 'answered'? Do I use the _Answer Your Question_ button?

Comment: bananasareyellow, I would invite @JYoung to post the answer as an answer, so credit can be given where credit is due.  If JYoung is unconcerned about reputation and declines the invitation, you could post the answer yourself and accept that.

Comment: Go ahead bananasareyellow, post the answer. You understand it better than me now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation is given by @jyoung in the comments below my original posting.

The last line of `requiresExtraField` also tests `cenv.opts.workAroundReflectionEmitBugs`. This flag appears to be set in [fscopts.fs](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Compiler.Service/blob/f3e5a7cc181e921115e91944ad17d9cc54cefb6f/src/fsharp/fscopts.fs#L950). The line of code is:

```
workAroundReflectionEmitBugs=tcConfig.isInteractive; // REVIEW: is this still required?
```

So the problem of the extra `__dummy` field only occurs in F# Interactive.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of whether the logic for `isEmptyStruct` is backwards, as it appears to be.

Comment: @ildjarn: You are right, it doesn't. I marked it as answered because my principle issue was the size of the struct due to the presence of the dummy field. That test is still questionable.